# Database Date Displays 1970-01-01 00:00:00 but it displays correctly inside wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, datepicker, export

Inside Wordpress my Date/Time custom field displays the correct date. But when I export the data I see this date/time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00

How can I export the data with the correct date/time.

Comment: Export the data using what? Whatever you're using looks to be having a problem with the date field because 1 January 1970 equates to 0.

Comment: Both the WP All Export plugin and the Default export under Tools in Wordpress give me the same results

Comment: Wordpress displays the correct date and so do my PHP templates. Its only when I export the data that I see 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

There was a bug in WP All Export. They sent me a patch